# Postgres odd behavior with indices

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a `datavalue` table with ~200M rows or so, with indices on both `site_id` and `paramter_id`. I need to execute queries like "return all sites with data" and "return all parameters with data". The `site` table has only 200 rows or so, and the `parameter` table has only 100 or so rows.

The `site` query is fast and uses the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select *
from site
where exists (
      select 1 from datavalue
      where datavalue.site_id = site.id limit 1
);

Seq Scan on site  (cost=0.00..64.47 rows=64 width=113) (actual time=0.046..1.106 rows=89 loops=1)
  Filter: (SubPlan 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 39
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.44..0.47 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=128)
          ->  Index Only Scan using ix_datavalue_site_id on datavalue  (cost=0.44..8142.71 rows=248930 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=128)
                Index Cond: (site_id = site.id)
                Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.361 ms
Execution time: 1.149 ms
```

The same query for parameters is rather slow and does NOT use the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select *
from parameter
where exists (
      select 1 from datavalue
      where datavalue.parameter_id = parameter.id limit 1
);

Seq Scan on parameter  (cost=0.00..20.50 rows=15 width=2648) (actual time=2895.972..21331.701 rows=15 loops=1)
  Filter: (SubPlan 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 6
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1015.790..1015.790 rows=1 loops=21)
          ->  Seq Scan on datavalue  (cost=0.00..502127.10 rows=1476987 width=0) (actual time=1015.786..1015.786 rows=1 loops=21)
                Filter: (parameter_id = parameter.id)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 7739355
Planning time: 0.123 ms
Execution time: 21331.736 ms
```

What the deuce is going on here? Alternatively, whats a good way to do this?

Some of the table description:

```
id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('datavalue_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
value DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
site_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
parameter_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
deployment_id INTEGER,
instrument_id INTEGER,
invalid BOOLEAN,
Indexes:
    "datavalue_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "datavalue_datetime_utc_site_id_parameter_id_instrument_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (datetime_utc, site_id, parameter_id, instrument_id)
    "ix_datavalue_instrument_id" btree (instrument_id)
    "ix_datavalue_parameter_id" btree (parameter_id)
    "ix_datavalue_site_id" btree (site_id)
    "tmp_idx" btree (site_id, datetime_utc)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "datavalue_instrument_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (instrument_id) REFERENCES instrument(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_parameter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parameter_id) REFERENCES parameter(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_site_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES coastal.site(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_statistic_type_id_fkey"
```

Edit: Here's the count distribution

```
select count(parameter_id), parameter_id from datavalue group by parameter_id

88169   14
2889171 8
15805   17
8570    12
4257262 21
3947049 15
1225902 2
4091090 3
103877  10
633764  11
994442  18
49232   20
14935   4
563638  13
2955919 7
```

Comment: I suspect there are duplicates in the correlated subquery for the second query.So it need to get all rows with `datavalue.parameter_id = parameter.id` before LIMIT 1

Comment: Could you show the result of `\d datavalue`?

Comment: Attached some of the DDL

Comment: @Mihai what do you mean exactly? But yes, there are many rows in the `datavalue` table for each site_id and parameter_id

Comment: The subquery after exists is run once for every `datavalue.parameter_id = parameter.id` But if you have duplicate values it will take a lot longer than for unique values.The rows removed by that condition is 7 millions so each time 7 millions rows are filtered out .

Comment: Is there any other way to do these queries?

Comment: Table `site` has 128 rows and `parameter` has 21 rows. What happens if you insert 100 dummy rows (which get filtered out anyways) into `parameter`? What is the distribution of `parameter` in `datavalue`? Does a single `parameter.id` fill most of the `datavalue` table? (E.g., could we see `select count(parameter_id), parameter_id from datavalue group by parameter_id;`?

Comment: 88169 14
2889171 8
15805 17
8570 12
4257262 21
3947049 15
1225902 2
4091090 3
103877 10
633764 11
994442 18
49232 20
14935 4
563638 13
2955919 7

Comment: thats count(par_id), par_id

Comment: Put in in your question, it is hard to read.

Comment: I'm thinking the optimizer decides it is better to just to a sequential scan because of the data distribution. See here, for a better explanation: https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/optimizer.pdf
So ... you could add `SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off; SET LOCAL enable_bitmapscan = off;` to your transaction since you know you are doing LIMIT 1.

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130698/1822

Comment: Just remove the useless `limit` in the subselect and Postgres _will_ choose a better plan: http://explain.depesz.com/s/AWdD (based on the test-setup from hruske)

Comment: `The subquery after exists is run once for every ...` a common misconception (caused by exposure to mysql, IIRC): check the query plan. The subquery is an integral part of the query plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** as a_horse_with_no_name has mentioned, you can remove the LIMIT 1 and query will use index.

Apparently PostgreSQL incorrectly assumes it is going to touch the whole database if you do a subquery and overlooks the LIMIT 1. (Which turns out to be unnecessary.)

I generated the same distribution on my laptop with:

```
create table testtbl (id integer, par_id integer);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) values (0,0 );
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 4 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+14935);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 12 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+8570);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 17 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+15805);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 20 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+49232);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 14 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+88169);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 10 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+103877);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 2 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+1225902);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 8 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+2889171);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 7 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+2955919);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 3 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+4091090);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 13 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+563638);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 11 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+633764);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 18 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+994442);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 15 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+3947049);
insert into testtbl (id, par_id) select "generate_series", 21 from generate_series((select max(id) from testtbl), (select max(id) from testtbl)+4257262);
delete from testtbl where id = 0 and par_id = 0;
create index testtbl_paridx on testtbl (par_id);
create table parameter (id integer);
insert into parameter select * from generate_series (1, 28);
analyze testtbl;
```

Then if I run query:

```
testdb=# explain analyze select * from parameter where exists (select 1 from testtbl where testtbl.par_id = parameter.id limit 1);
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on parameter  (cost=0.00..643.29 rows=1200 width=4) (actual time=4083.514..54216.575 rows=15 loops=1)
   Filter: (SubPlan 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 13
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.25 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1936.299..1936.299 rows=1 loops=28)
           ->  Seq Scan on testtbl  (cost=0.00..369619.35 rows=1455927 width=0) (actual time=1936.294..1936.294 rows=1 loops=28)
                 Filter: (par_id = parameter.id)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 14870626
 Planning time: 0.151 ms
 Execution time: 54216.620 ms
(10 rows)
```

If I disable sequential scan:

```
testdb=# set local enable_seqscan = off;
SET

testdb=# explain analyze select * from parameter where exists (select 1 from testtbl where testtbl.par_id = parameter.id limit 1);
                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on parameter  (cost=10000000000.00..10000001395.02 rows=1200 width=4) (actual time=0.077..0.563 rows=15 loops=1)
   Filter: (SubPlan 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 13
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.44..0.57 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=28)
           ->  Index Only Scan using ix_testtbl_par on testtbl  (cost=0.44..188678.87 rows=1455927 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=28)
                 Index Cond: (par_id = parameter.id)
                 Heap Fetches: 15
 Planning time: 0.169 ms
 Execution time: 0.605 ms
(10 rows)
```

Fast, but a bit hackish. You want to use [SET **LOCAL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html), in order not to disable the sequential scan for all queries. SET LOCAL is in effect until transaction commit.

Update: **A better option** is to remove the LIMIT 1 altogether as recommended by a_horse_with_no_name.

```
testdb=# explain analyze select * from parameter where exists (select 1 from testtbl where testtbl.par_id = parameter.id );
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.44..1591.08 rows=1200 width=4) (actual time=0.070..0.492 rows=15 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on parameter  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.018 rows=28 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using testtbl_paridx on testtbl  (cost=0.44..29379.76 rows=1455923 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=28)
         Index Cond: (par_id = parameter.id)
         Heap Fetches: 15
 Planning time: 0.216 ms
 Execution time: 0.532 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for looking into that. Yeah, that does feel dirty but it does work...

Comment: The test-setup is very helpful (+1 for that) and it shows that fooling around with `enable_seqscan` is unnecessary if the useless `limit 1` is removed: http://explain.depesz.com/s/AWdD

Comment: The test setup is very usefull, but it omits the primary and foreign key constraints. Besides: testtbl.par_id is integer **NOT NULL** , which could make a big difference, because being an FK this implies that the cardinality is constrained to the domain of parameter.id.

Comment: Yeah the limit 1 was the offender. Removed it and it does indeed use the index properly. Many thanks guys.

Comment: I just want to say nice job on the test setup, really great bit of effort on your part.